# Is there a way to set a name from variable for a new list?

Tags: java, android

I tried and search answer for this question as this seems trivial but I really couldn't find it. (Maybe I don't know how to ask the right question).

Is there a way to do the following?

```
private void createAList(String a) {

   List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

Because I want to have a list created with every change of data and I want a specific name for it that will be provided in String a.

I hope I've explained it clearly enough. :)

Edit: Ok, I see I didn't explained it clear enough.......
Although I don't know how can I make it even simpler it is quite straight forward.

I want to create this method and then use it like that:

```
String name = ben;
createAList(name);
```

And it will create:

```
List<String> ben = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Variables don't have names at runtime. They are a mere convenience for programmers to help them understand the code. So wanting to give a list a "name" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: can you please explain the exact use case?

Comment: @Ayush what on earth do you mean (no pun intended)?

Comment: probably using sarcasm to bash on op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the variable's name.

You could create a Hashmap:

```
HashMap <String, ArrayList> valuesMap;
```

And then

```
private void createAList(String a) { 
  List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
  valuesMap.put(a, valueList);
}
```

Then you can use the list search ing the variable "a" value in HashMap's keys

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks Andy!! I'm new here